# Is it a good idea to read full file in one shot?

Tags: c++, c, file, file-io

I am reading full file in a shot, Also movie file. Then I am using that buffer to write a new file like 50KB in a shot. Correct me it's wrong?
Below is sample code:

```
FILE * pFile;
  long lSize;
  char * buffer;
  size_t result;

  pFile = fopen ( "myfile.bin" , "rb" );
  if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

  // obtain file size:
  fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
  lSize = ftell (pFile);
  rewind (pFile);

  // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
  buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
  if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

  // copy the file into the buffer:
  result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
  if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

  /* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */

  // terminate
  fclose (pFile);
  free (buffer);
```

Comment: One way to test this is to write your buffer to a new file and use a comparison utility to ensure they are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream reader model is used for reading file because there is no limit of file size, but there is a limit of memory that you can use. There is no problem if your file size is small enough to be stored completely in memory, but if you're reading media file for example 4GB+ DVD ISO i think your program will consume too much memory and cannot work on low-spec computer.

Answer (score 1):

It is okey until you have enough free memory... But beware, if the file is greater than 4GB and you use 32 bit compiler.

Comment: I do not know where your program will run. If you are sure that your computer will have enough memory then it is ok but otherwise not. But if you do not need to perform operations on the whole file it better to read file chunks.